# Laravel:8.x Target class [ArticlesController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Hello my code is giving me this error:  "Target class [ArticlesController] does not exist." i tried to uncomment  "protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';"  in RouteServiceProvider then it says:  "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Article' not found"

ArticlesController:

```
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{

   public function index()
   {
    $articles = Article::latest()->get();

    return view('articles.index', ['articles' => $articles]);
  }

   public function show($id)
  {
    $article = Article::find($id);

    return view('articles.show', ['article' => $article]);
 }
}
```

Route:

```
   Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
 });

 Route::get('/about', function () {
 return view('about', [
    'articles' => App\Models\Article::take(3)->latest()->get()
]);
});

Route::get('/articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::get('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@show');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Laravel 8 the route syntax has changed. You have to define the full path for controller class and specify the method.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController;

Route::get('/articles', [ArticlesController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/articles/{article}', [ArticlesController::class, 'show']);
```

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Article' not found

Comment: @proprogrammer probably an error in your controller. add "use App\Models\Article;" at the top of the file.